# Would an Elmer's wood filler color match a Minwax wood finish color?

Tags: woodworking, staining

I recently stained some red oak using Minwax Wood Finish in Golden Oak colour.  I need a hardening wood filler to close up the seams.  Would Elmer's Wood Filler in Golden Oak complement this?  Or, should I pick a different colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you match the filler to the raw wood color as best you can. Then you stain and finish. But the results are definitely variable. If you are obsessive about making it match, I'd suggest a series of tests on similar wood with various combinations of filler, stain, and process.